# Get 2nd highest salary if some employee can same salary

Tags: mysql, sql

```
employee Table;

+--------+------------------+
| emp_id | emp_name  salary |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 1      | James    |  2000  |
| 2      | Jack     |   4000 |
| 3      | Henry    |   6000 |
| 5      | John     |   8000 |
| 6      | Martin   |   6000 |`
| 7      | Deny     |   6000 |
```

I want to get second highest salary & according to the table second highest salary will be:-

```
+--------+------------------+
| emp_id | emp_name  salary |
+--------+----------+--------+
| 3      | Henry    |   6000 |
| 6      | Martin   |   6000 |`
| 7      | Deny     |   6000 |
```

How can i achive this ?

I can't use :-

```
select * from employee order by salary desc Limit 1,1
```

because it always show only one record.

Any help wil be appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Your example is showing the 2nd lowest salary (4000). I've replied with a query that will get that. The 2nd highest salary is 6000. You may want to reword the question title and description to make it clear that you want the 2nd lowest salary.

Comment: Try generic solution as provided below and it will solve your problem for further such comparisons generically.

Comment: Which `mysql version` are you using?

Answer (score 2):

This query can be used:

```
select * from employee where salary =
(select max(salary) from employee where salary <
(select max(salary) from employee));
```

For the dataset, this is the result:

```
+--------+----------+--------+
| emp_id | emp_name | salary |
+--------+----------+--------+
|      3 | Henry    |   6000 |
|      6 | Martin   |   6000 |
|      7 | Deny     |   6000 |
+--------+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Good concept, but it returns the 2nd lowest salary instead of the 2nd highest

Comment: Right @Andomar. There is a mismatch in the problem description and the desired output shown. I've noted that as a comment in the problem section. The desired output seems to be the 2nd lowest salary, which this query gives.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,yes,sorry!,i've modified the question now.

Comment: Updated answer to get 2nd highest salary.

Comment: @Andomar - Updated answer to get 2nd highest.

Comment: This will work fine but suppose a case where there is a requirement to fetch 7th highest or 10th highest salary, there would be number of subqueries required. Please look for the generic solution in the answers provided by me.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the immediate lower value than maximum in the inline sub query (query in the brackets),then you run select query based on the results it throws back:

```
select `emp_id`, `emp_name`, `salary` from employee where `salary` = (select `salary` from employee where `salary` < MAX(salary) order by salary desc limit 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL query should be generic to handle Nth highest salary.
For example: From below table, we need to figure out 3rd/Nth highest salary. In this example b, d should be printed.

```
Empname    Salary
A           400
B           200
C           100
D           200
E           300
```

Use query like this: Here N should be 3 for 3rd highest salary and so on.

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee Emp1
WHERE (N-1) = ( 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Emp2.Salary))
FROM Employee Emp2 WHERE Emp2.Salary > Emp1.Salary)
```

I hope this generic query helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `MySQL 8.0` or higher version, you can try `DENSE_RANK()` window function, refer documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank).

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        e.*,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER w AS 'rank'
    FROM
        employee e
    WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY e.salary DESC)
) a

WHERE a.rank = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the reply.

I have tried the following query & it's working for me.

```
select * from employee where salary=(select salary from employee order by salary desc limit 1,1)
```

Comment: This won't work in the situation where there are multiple rows having the highest salary. To see this, execute this statement and then run your query. insert into employee values(8,'Tom',8000); It returns employees with salary 8000, not the correct value of 6000.

Comment: Thanks J.S., yes you're right.                                                        select * from employee where salary=(select DISTINCT(salary) from employee order by salary desc limit 1,1). it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to approach this using a subquery:

```
select e.*
from employee e
where e.salary = (select distinct e2.salary
                  from employee e2
                  order by e2.salary desc
                  limit 1 offset 1
                 );
```

The subquery can also be moved to the `from` clause, because it is not correlated.  It is simply ordering all the distinct salaries and using `limit`/`offset` to obtain the second one.  Without using window functions (i.e. `dense_rank()`), this seems like the clearest solution.